# Adding parent folder name to feature name in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have created many shapefiles with the same name and every shapefile is in its own folder with a specific name.

For example:

```
folder1\polygon.shp
folder2\polygon.shp
folder3\polygon.shp
```

And I want the features to be like: folder1_polygon.shp, folder2_polygon.shp, etc...

How to add a parent folder name to a feature name using the ModelBuilder?

Comment: Try [Parse Path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) or perhaps [Calculate Value](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm). [Example here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215209/modelbuilder-using-parse-path-in-iterative-model-to-include-folder-name-in-outp)

Comment: Nice! You can answer your own question if you like